# Serialization without Boost.Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, mpi

I'm trying to implement a simple serialization/deserialization method for my code to be able to pass an object over the network using MPI. In an ideal world I would have used `Boost.Serialization` and `Boost.MPI` for that but they are not installed on some of the clusters I have access to so I'm considering doing this myself.

My strategy is to serialize every object into a `std::stringstream` object and then send a message via `MPI_Send` using `MPI_CHAR` as the datatype. In such a case I would pass `std::stringstream::str()::c_str()` as the pointer and `std::streaingstream::str()::size()*sizeof(char)` as the size of the message.

I've figured how to serialize everything into a `std::stringstream` object. My deserialization method also takes a `std::stringstream` object and deserializes everything back. This works fine except I do not know how to create a `std::stringstream` object from an array of `char`s and avoid the extra copy from the array into the stream. Should I change my deserialization method to directly work with an array of `char` using `memcpy` instead?

Comment: Why not bundle a build (stripped to only what you need) of Boost with the application? Then you won't have to worry about reinventing the wheel.

Comment: see if this fits your requirements https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Comment: When sending binary values you should use `MPI_BYTE` and not `MPI_CHAR` to avoid any possible conversions done by the MPI library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPI way of doing this, would be using `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack`. Of course that is C and might not be as convenient as something using C++ features. For a simple example see http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/mpiexmpl/src/bcast/C/pack/solution.html

Comment: This is interesting. Right now I have decided I memcpy everything into an array of `char`, send that, and then deserialize the array on the other process. Does MPI_Pack also do something similar or can it avoid the extra copy?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `istrstream`, which extracts from a `char` array. The header for this is `<strstream>`. And, yes, formally it's deprecated in the C++ Standard. The committee indulged in a great deal of wishful thinking in its early days. `istrstream` is not going to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is the right way to go, the concrete question "except I do not know how to create a `std::stringstream` object from an array of chars" was not answered yet.

The answer is that effectively you can't.

Presumably have an object already in memory and you want so see it as an `stringstream`, even if you can make it work the `stringstream` will not be able to grow further in the existing memory (which is an useful property of the stream buffer.).

Also there is no much point into making heroic attempts to *not* copy data that is going to be send in an MPI message.
MPI might end up copying the data internally anyway, to "pinned" memory for example depending on the exact method of communication (buffered, unbuffered, asynchronous, etc).
That is my understanding.

If the data is too large to be copied at all (e.g. many gigabytes) then it is better to use `MPI_Datatype`s which can be a real challenge to handle in generic ways.

BTW, the accepted answer is what my MPI library does internally https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-mpi3, it is probably what the original Boost.MPI does too.